# C++ IDE with function auto complete

Tags: linux, ide, ubuntu, c++

When I was on xubuntu 13.10, codeblocks worked, sometimes. When I was on Windows, codeblocks worked great. Now I am on Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit, Codeblocks doesn't work, it crashes as soon as it stars. I want an alternative. Didn't find any that satisfies me.

I am looking for a specific feature, that I have not found in any IDE so far. I want function autocomplete:

> If I write co, it should suggest cout, if I write a library called
>   example.h and go to main to include it, it should suggest that. If I
>   write someFunction twice in the same file, it should detect that I
>   wrote the function above and autoplete it.

I have tried Anjuta, didn't like it a bit, and it doesn't support this feature. I have tried eclipse CDT plugin, and I loved it, I love the fact that it keeps warning you about errors, and there's brackets autocomplete, but no function autocomplete. I tried Netbeans sometimes ago, and as far as I can remember, this feature isn't available (right?).

So far, I have found this feature only in codeblocks and in text editors such as sublime text editor 3, which is great but not an IDE (unless you know some plugin that would transform it into a perfect C++ IDE, compile button, show errors, warnings and so forth).

Autocomplete is essential because I don't have time in my computer science exams to write functions, codeblocks saved my life many times, never worried about functions, typo mistakes or brackets.

So I want an IDE, as close to codeblocks as it gets, with autocomplete functions and brackets and everything.

Vim not an option, even if it could be turned to an IDE, not now, I am still learning it, I can't rely on it yet in my exams. I didn't master it yet. I could go for Emacs if you can transform it into C++ IDE that has the features I need.

Comment: What do you mean by "no function autocomplete in eclipse CDT" - have you tried pressing ctrl + space and didn't get the results you wanted? Another thing is if you felt familiar with CodeBlocks perhaps you should try to fix the installation first and then change it with another IDE :)

Comment: @dimzak just tried it, ctrl + space doesn't work, I'm using eclipse ADT with CDT plugin installed, not eclipse CDT, well it's CDT but the plugin. As for Codeblocks, it just crashes i see no errors

Comment: @dimzak kinda same bug as this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/codeblocks/+bug/416475

Comment: Evneutally [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/) works for you. It's very lightweight, but has a lot of plugins. I think it has the autocomplete function your looking for. Some information from Chromium project: http://www.chromium.org/developers/sublime-text

Comment: @moose yes it has autocomplete but I don't know if it can be called an IDE (I don't know if I can add a debug button and compile button and possibly add a dictionary that would tell what's the use of this function and so on) sublime is my primary text editor, I can't call it an IDE though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest [QT Creator](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aTools%3a%3aQtCreator). Don't be fooled by the name, you can use it for any C++ project, even without QT.
It has all he features you're asking (autocomplete, compilation and so...).
On top of that, it's multi-platform.

Comment: +1 for qt creator, definitely the best c++ ide out there. So fast and responsive...it also has valgrind and gdb integrated!